# I'm not able to set an adapter in recycler View

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, adapter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x3bD.jpg) i want this type of activity in my MainActivity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyqnm.png)But MainActivity is Empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Hiy.png)g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbgNT.png) there is code that will set an Adapter to MainActivity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remove tag `android-studio` as that tag is for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have a compile problem? Do you have a runtime problem? What's the error? What are you trying to do? Please help us, so we can help you.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to set an adapter activity in the main activity . This is the code adding an adapter Activity in MainActivity but this doesn't work.                                                                                                                          adapter = new VideoFoldersAdapter(mediaFiles, allFolderList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();